# How to access return data of jQuery.ajax()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm using the following code to make an AJAX call:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: href,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {},
    dataType: "json",
    error: function(req, resulttype, exc)
    {
      // do error handling
    },
    success: function(data)
    {
      for (var tracklist in data) {
        console.log(tracklist.name); // undefined
        console.log(tracklist['name']); // undefined
      }
    }
  });
```

What I return to the AJAX request is:

```
{"5":{"id":5,"name":"2 tracks","count":2},"4":{"id":4,"name":"ddddd","count":1},"7":{"id":7,"name":"Final test","count":2}}
```

What I would like to know is how to access the name attribute of the current tracklist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

```
console.log(data[tracklist].name);
```

instead of

```
console.log(tracklist.name);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to iterate over those objects, it would be better if you returned an array:

```
[{"id":5,"name":"2 tracks","count":2},{"id":4,"name":"ddddd","count":1},{"id":7,"name":"Final test","count":2}]
```

Then, you could use a for-loop similar to what you were trying:

```
  for (var tracklist in data) {
    console.log(data[tracklist].id);
    console.log(data[tracklist].name);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the loop:

```
for (var tracklist in data) {
  console.log(tracklist.name); // undefined
  console.log(tracklist['name']); // undefined
}
```

`tracklist` is the key of each element, not its value.

Thus:

```
for (var tracklist in data) {
  console.log(data[tracklist].name); // ... or ...
  console.log(data[tracklist]['name']);
}
```